# PHP drop down menu with Javascript alert

Tags: php, javascript, drop-down-menu, alert

I have created a simple drop-down menu in PHP:

```
<td> Privilege: </td>
<td><select name="privilege">
<?php 
    $position_list = array(
                1 => "Chair", 
                2 => "SACA",
                5 => "Faculty",
                0 => "Disable User",
                );
    foreach ($position_list as $priv_id=>$position) {
    echo "<option value= \"{$priv_id}\"";
            if ($priv_id == $sel_user['privilege']) {
                 echo " selected"; 
            }
            echo ">{$position}</option>";   
    }   
?></td></select>        
        </tr>       
        </tr>
```

I am wondering if it is possible to include some Javascript. So, when the user selects "Disable User", a message saying "are you sure you want to disable this user?" pops up. 
Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Make abstraction of the PHP here and focus on html, then try to learn some Javascript, what have you tried so far?

Comment: your "</td>" should be after "</select>" btw

Comment: Unless the site updates dynamically (i.e. with AJAX), you might want to just re-direct the user to another page where they can confirm their choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is not displaying the alert - that's fairly simple - but keeping track of the value the select element used to have. After all, it wouldn't be much use if the user clicked "no" and the user was disabled anyway.

In order to do this, I suggest the easiest thing to do would be to use a hidden input element to store the original value. You can then refer to the to set the options back correctly.

Something like this (HTML structure corrected here, please pay attention ;-) ):

```
<td>Privilege:</td>
<td>
  <!-- note the onchange event -->
  <select name="privilege" onchange="checkDisable(this);">
<?php 

    // Define the options
    $position_list = array(
      1 => "Chair", 
      2 => "SACA",
      5 => "Faculty",
      0 => "Disable User",
    );

    // Create the list
    foreach ($position_list as $priv_id=>$position) {
      echo "<option value= \"{$priv_id}\"";
      if ($priv_id == $sel_user['privilege']) {
        echo " selected=\"selected\""; 
      }
      echo ">{$position}</option>";   
    }   

?></select>
  <input type="hidden" id="privilege_old_val" value="<?php echo $sel_user['privilege']; ?>" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkDisable(element) {

      // Firstly check if the user selected the disable option, then get them to confirm it
      if (element.options[element.selectedIndex].value == 0 && !confirm("Are you sure you want to disable this user?")) {
        // If they didn't confirm it, loop the options...
        for (var i = 0; i < element.options.length; i++) {
          // Find the option with the old value...
          if (element.options[i].value == document.getElementById('privilege_old_val').value) {
            // ...and set the select back to that option
            element.selectedIndex = i;
          } // if
        } // for
      } // if

      // Update the input that tracks the old value with the current value
      document.getElementById('privilege_old_val').value = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;

    }
  </script>
</td>
```

Comment: Hi -- WOW! That is a great answer. I tried pasting that into my code, but it's not updating to the database. Is that because I need to change some things around? Thank you very much!

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your DB code - was it working before? Make sure the server is still receiving a sensible value in `$_GET['privilege']` or `$_POST['privilege']`, whichever you are using

Comment: EDIT: nevermind, that was my mistake. It does work perfectly! Awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `onchange` event:

```
<select name="privilege" onchange="if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value === 0)confirm('Are you sure you want to disable this user?')">
```

Comment: Hi, great suggestion. I tried something very similar earlier but it's not working. This is probably a really stupid question but: do I have to change this code at all or can I paste it in? Sorry - I've never programmed in Javascript, but I thought it would be a nice feature to add-in

Answer (score 0):

This JavaScript should do it for you:

```
<select name="Select1" onchange="if(this.value==0) confirm('are you sure you want to disable this user?')">
<option value="1">Chair</option>
<option value="2">SACA</option>
<option value="5">Faculty</option>
<option value="0">Disable user</option>
</select>​​​
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I am trying to stick with creating the drop-down in pHp so I can keep track of selected values in the database (and previously selected values will be highlighted, etc)

Comment: You can still create the dropdown in PHP, just add in the onlick JavaScript part.

Comment: would alert() not do instead of confirm()

Comment: @gunnx - `alert()` just gives you an OK button to click. `confirm()` gives you a yes/no option which will return true/false based on the user's choice.

Comment: @NVidovic - Glad to help. If you believe this answers your question, please consider upvoting it and/or selecting it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes I know that but you are not doing anything with the return value of confirm()

Comment: @gunnx - The OP didn't specify what they wanted to do with the result.

Comment: It might be worth showing an example of how they could use the result. As you would expect something to happen if you select OK versus Cancel.

Comment: @gunnx - seems a little late for that, an answer was already chosen.